# La répétition d'une phrase, qu'est ce qu'elle signifie ?

Tags: grammaire

Il y a un très beau poème par Louis Aragon, « Ce que dit Elsa ». J'ai une question à propos d'un extrait:

> Tu me dis Si tu veux que je t'aime et je t'aime 
>   Il faut que ce portrait que de moi tu peindras 
>   Ait comme un ver vivant au fond du chrysanthème […]

Comme il est facile de voir, M. Aragon évitait la ponctuation. *Donc la première ligne de cet extrait est ambiguë, je crois. Ou non ? C'est ma question.* Je vais la préciser.

Le premier sens est bien évident. On mets des parenthèses autout de la deuxième « et je t'aime ». Le résultat, c'est que Elsa simplement n'a pas manqué une occasion à déclarer qu'elle l'aime. « *Si tu veux que je t'aime (et je t'aime, en fait)* »

Le deuxième sens, je ne sais pas s'il est présent en français. En russe, on double parfois une phrase pour la faire signifier qu'une action se dure longtemps, ou bien qu'une action est intense, profonde. Donc, « *Si tu veux que je t'aime très fort* »…

*Ce deuxième sens, existe-t-il en français ?* C'est ma question en mots précis.

Merci beaucoup !

Comment: Le deuxième sens existe bel et bien: [_Et ça continue encore et encore, C'est que le début d'accord, d'accord..._](https://www.paroles.net/francis-cabrel/paroles-encore-et-encore)

Comment: Depuis, j'ai trouvé [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper) un example pour le deuxième sens: «*Elles couraient et couraient. Leur cœur tapait …* ». Évidemment, ça veut dire qu'elles couraient pendant longtemps, bien que rien n'a été dit de l'intensité de leur course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malgré l'absence de ponctuation, la première interprétation n'est guère plausible. La phrase d'Elsa peut se simplifier comme ceci:

> Si tu veux que je t'aime, il faut que ce portrait que tu peindras ait...

Comme le reste du poème, il s'agit d'une menace et Elsa ne peut pas se contredire en affirmant qu'elle l'aime au milieu d'une phrase où elle pose ses conditions.

C'est donc le deuxième sens qu'il faut préférer au premier:

> Tu me dis : « Si tu veux que je t'aime et je t'aime... »

La répétition est une figure de style qui existe aussi en français.

Il est généralement recommandé de l'éviter sauf pour marquer un effet particulier qui ici est simplement celui d'une répétition, le renouvellement de la preuve d'amour d'Elsa pour Aragon.

On retrouve cette figure de style dans :

> [Et ça continue encore et encore](http://www.franciscabrel.com/encore-et-encore/)

Après réflexion, **une troisième interprétation est possible et c'est celle qui me parait maintenant la plus vraisemblable**:

Avec elle, le ***et je t'aime*** ne serait pas un effet de répétition mais une incise du poète qui déclare son amour au milieu de la phrase où Elsa pose ses conditions :

> Tu me dis : « Si tu veux que je t'aime » et je t'aime « Il faut que ce portrait que de moi tu peindras... »

C'est donc Aragon qui s'exprime, pas Elsa.

J'ai trouvé une [source confirmant cette dernière interprétation](http://francais113.skyrock.com/2498691835-CE-QUE-DIT-ELSA.html):

> Dans le dernier quintile de notre extrait (qui est aussi celui du poème tout entier), cette situation d'énonciation, en apparence stable, simple et répétitive, bascule soudain. Le « tu » du vers 21 est en effet, cette fois, celui d'Elsa, dont les propos sont rapportés à l'identique du vers 1 par le poète ( « si tu veux que je t'aime »). **Celui-ci, pour la première et seule fois, dit « je » dans une brève incise : « et je t'aime »**.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de votre recherche ! Oui, c'est une intreprétation très intéressante… Logiquement, néanmoins, il n'y a aucun problème avec une implication qui est vraie quand la prémisse est vraie et la conclusion est vraie. Aragon n'a pas encore essayé à faire un poème qui complète tout ce que sa femme veut voir « inauguré », donc il n'a pas encore violé les conditions de sa réussite… Donc, elle peut l'aimer encore… Et je ne crois pas que c'était une menace ; plutôt une suggestion, une profession de foi.

Answer (score 3):

S'il avait voulu créer cette répétition, je pense qu'il aurait écrit quelque chose comme (ce n'est pas très beau, je ne suis pas poète):

Si tu veux que je t'aime et **que** je t'aime

Même si on met la licence poétique dans le coup, l'idée d'une répétition sonne très bizarre. Quand j'ai lu les vers dans votre question, j'ai immédiatement pensé comme vous.
Je pense que votre première interprétation est la bonne, pas la seconde.

Comment: Dommage je ne peux pas accepter deux réponses. C'est ce que j'ai voulu savoir : il y a des gens qui pensent que la deuxième interprétation est bonne, et il y a d'autre gens qui pensent que la première interprétation (la plus poétique, à mon avis) est bonne. Merci beaucoup de votre réponse ; une étoile a brillé sur l'heure de notre rencontre ! (Une salutation elphique.)

Comment: Elen sila lumenn' omentielvo, aussi!

Comment: Pour être le mec embêtant: Rajouter le *que* ne clarifie pas la phrase, car on peut considérer le *que* comme une emphase: _"Si tu veux que je t'aime - et que je t'aime! -"_

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que c'est tout à fait plausible.

Je ne suis pas un expert en Aragon, ni même d'ailleurs un expert en poésie, mais, dans *Et moi, et moi, et moi* de Dutronc, on entend :

> Sept cent millions de chinois. **Et moi, et moi, et moi**. Avec ma vie, mon petit chez-moi. Mon mal de tête, mon point au foie. J'y pense et puis j'oublie. **C'est la vie, c'est la vie**.

Souvent dans la musique, et particulièrement dans la musique qui se veut populaire, on prend des raccourcis, et on se facilite la tâche : *il me manque deux syllabes ? Allez, répétition*.

Je ne pense pas, par contre, que mon exemple fasse partie de ce cas, du moins pour la première partie. Ici, Dutronc ramène son "moi", *à lui, à lui, et encore à lui* pour souligner l'égocentrisme de son "moi". On peut donc parler d'intensité, et donc le deuxième sens existe bien !